# How to create console single file executable from nsis

Tags: python, console, executable, nsis, py2exe

i have python program and i have converted into executable using py2exe program. My program is console application and it has various options as usage.

```
For Example:
            c:\>program.exe -h 
                 usage: For help option
```

it works fine when i converted into exe file using py2exe but when i used nsis and made single file executable, every time i open "example.exe" from my command prompt it pops out console window and it ends, Is there any way that i can pass arguement in the my program

Comment: Could you please show the NSIS code where you start the program?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you click on it, the exe is executing in a shell and the shell is quiting when the program is done. To keep persistence, you'll want to open a shell then run the command from the shell. If this is too much work or too complicated (and yes I've heard these comments from experienced developers speaking about themselves than the target user), then you'll want to put in some way to make it sleep in your program to wait for input from the user before exiting, but you'll still want shortcuts to pass the options in.

Ultimately, the best solution is just to run the command in the desired environment or build a gui to take options and display the output instead of doing it all in the cli.